# what are draw backs of using custom HTML tags?

Tags: html

what are most critical draw backs of using custom HTML tags? I need to create custom HTML5 tags and looked it up and found pros and cons list but now I'm looking for a draw back that might lead to a huge failure. can anyone help me with that please.

Comment: Are you asking about [custom elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/) (which follow a very specific set of rules) or "just making up stuff that browsers / search engines / assistive technology / etc have to error correct for"?

Comment: I'm asking about custom elements specifically. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition a custom tag is an HTML element that its properties are defined by programmers as opposed to the user agent. basically, custom elements provide a tool for programmers to build their own  DOM elements. Programmers can always use non-standard elements in their documents, with application-specific behavior added after the fact by scripting or similar, such elements have historically been non-conforming and not very functional. creating a custom element, we can inform the parser how to properly construct an element and how elements of that class should react to changes.

having said that, the biggest drawback is that, simply defining an element doesn’t mean that the element inherits all attributes and properties as you intended. for example if you create a    tag, that doesn’t mean that your newly created tag is suppose to act like a button.